# Why does the "each" iterator method break rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec2, ruby-1.9.2

### Background

I'm attempting to test my models.

#### app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :payor_transactions, class_name: 'Transaction', inverse_of: :payor, foreign_key: :payor_id
  has_many :payee_transactions, class_name: 'Transaction', inverse_of: :payee, foreign_key: :payee_id

  def transactions
    transactions = Transaction.where(["payor_id=? OR payee_id=?", self.id, self.id])
    transactions
  end

end
```

#### app/models/transaction.rb

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :user

  belongs_to :payor, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :payee, class_name: 'User'

end
```

In the Transactions class, @user is an ephemeral object instance representing the user accessing the model.

#### spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  let(:user) { Factory(:user) }
  let(:user2) { Factory(:user) }
  let(:user3) { Factory(:user) }

  let(:transaction_user_user2) { Factory(:transaction, payor: user, payee: user2) }
  let(:transaction_user2_user) { Factory(:transaction, payor: user2, payee: user) }
  let(:transaction_user2_user3) { Factory(:transaction, payor: user2, payee: user3) }

  describe ".transactions" do
    it "should include payor and payee transactions but not 3rd party transactions" do
      user.transactions.should == [transaction_user_user2, transaction_user2_user]
      user2.transactions.should == [transaction_user_user2, transaction_user2_user, transaction_user2_user3]
      user3.transactions.should == [transaction_user2_user3]
    end
  end

end
```

Using rspec 2.6.4, factory_girl 2.1.2, rails 3.1.0, ruby 1.9.2p290. As shown, the spec passes.

### Problem

When I modify the `transactions` method in **app/models/user.rb** to iterate over the results such that it reads:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :payor_transactions, class_name: 'Transaction', inverse_of: :payor, foreign_key: :payor_id
  has_many :payee_transactions, class_name: 'Transaction', inverse_of: :payee, foreign_key: :payee_id

  def transactions
    transactions = Transaction.where(["payor_id=? OR payee_id=?", self.id, self.id])
    transactions.each {|transaction| transaction.user = self}
    transactions
  end

end
```

the method `transactions` now returns `[]` in rspec, *however it works perfectly in the app views*.

Since Transaction.user is ephemeral (representing the user accessing the transaction) it must be set (if it exists) every time a Transaction is initialized or built from db records.

**I'm at a loss for where to begin to debug this.**

All suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I'm still learning rspec, so I would assume this is an error in my configuration of rspec rather than a bug in rspec itself.

Comment: my spec_helper.rb, just in case: https://gist.github.com/1274147

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the fact that `let` is lazy. Basically what is happening is that the transactions are not even created yet when the `transactions` method is called in the test. Use `let!` for a non-lazy version. See [let and let!](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just return payor_transactions + payee_transactions instead of manually selecting them?

Comment: I intend to add paging, so I need the union to happen at the db level, but `transactions = self.payor_transactions + self.payee_transactions` would work.

Comment: Fair enough. Paging always makes things more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion from @obrok, the solution I settled on to retain the advantage of lazy-loading `let` in other tests was to touch each transaction before testing User#transactions as so:

```
describe ".transactions" do
  it "should include payor and payee transactions but not 3rd party transactions" do

    [transaction_user_user2, transaction_user2_user, transaction_user2_user3].each do |transaction|
      [transaction.payor_id, transaction.payee_id].each {|id| id.should_not be_nil }
    end

    user.transactions.should == [transaction_user_user2, transaction_user2_user]
    user2.transactions.should == [transaction_user_user2, transaction_user2_user, transaction_user2_user3]
    user3.transactions.should == [transaction_user2_user3]
  end
end
```